# Polymer 0.8 "Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined"

Tags: polymer

Recently I made the decision test out Polymer 0.8 rather than just read about it, however I've come across an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined".

I have a feeling it's something really simple that I've missed I can't seem to figure it out.

Below is my code which I've literally copied and pasted from the [feature overview](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/devguide/feature-overview.html) document:

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

<dom-module id="element-name">
  <style>
    /* CSS rules for your element */
  </style>
  <template>
    <!-- local DOM for your element -->

    <div>{{greeting}}</div> <!-- data bindings in local DOM -->
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  // element registration
  Polymer({
    is: "element-name",

    // add properties and methods on the element's prototype

    properties: {
      // declare properties for the element's public API
      greeting: {
        type: String,
        value: "Hello!"
      }
    }
  });
</script>

<element-name></element-name>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`webcomponents-lite.min.js` is the Polyfill for `Shadow DOM` and html `Imports` you should add this to you `main.html` page and not in your custom component.

Instead you should add the Polymer Library where you have added the Polyfill.

Below is an example code:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="element-name">
  <style>
    /* CSS rules for your element */
  </style>
  <template>
    <!-- local DOM for your element -->
```